# Pymongo multi update query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following query

```
DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
COLLECTION = 'scraper'
db = pymongo.MongoClient(DB_HOST)[COLLECTION]['scrap']
db.update({'indice':0, 'thread_id':{'$in':list_to_update}},{'updated':'yes'}, multi=True)
```

where list_to_update is a list of thread_ids where I would like to insert the field 'updated' to 'yes'

I am receiving the following error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: multi update only works with $ operators
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator:

```
db.update({'indice':0, 'thread_id': {'$in': list_to_update}},
          {'$set': {'updated':'yes'}}, 
          multi=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

from pymongo 3.1 use `update_many`:

```
xxx.update_many({'indice':0, 'thread_id': {'$in': list_to_update}}, {'$set': {'updated':'yes'}})
```

you can pass `upsert=False` if you dont need upsert.
Link to documentation:
[here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many)